# Mantra Biometric Device not able to get the data after scan (Android Integration)

Tags: android, biometrics

I am unable to get the data from mantra aeps device in OnActivityResult. I am successfully sending the PID options and device is also blanking and scanning the finger but not getting the data. I am using below code to get the data.

String result = data.getStringExtra("PIDDATA");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are using the wrong name. It should be

```
if (data != null)
String result = data.getStringExtra("PID_DATA");
```

also check the error code. It should be zero other than this is consider as error.

Comment: I'm facing problem in launching of MantraIris App while calling through intent on the devices with android version 10 and lower. Help me out. @Chaudhary Amar